# Persistence with Firebase Authentication

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-authentication, persistence

My issue is the following:
I want to keep the user logged in even if he closes and kills the flutter web app.
I'm using Firebase for the authentication.

I tried setting the persistence to 'local' after the initialization of the Firebase app but this didn't work. This way it stays logged if I don't kill the app.

```
//This is how my initialization looks like 
...
@override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    if(!fb.apps.isNotEmpty){
      fb.initializeApp(
        apiKey: myApiKey,
        authDomain: myAuthDomain,
        databaseURL: myDbURL,
        storageBucket: myStorageBucket,
        projectId: myProjID,
      );
    }
   fb.auth().setPersistence('local');
  }
...

//That's when I login the user with email and password

...
 onPressed: () async {
                  var loggedUser = await auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password);
                  if(loggedUser != null){
                    Navigator.pop(context, loggedUser);
                  }else{
                    print(loggedUser);
                  }
                }
...
```

Do you guys have any idea?

Comment: I solved using Chrome Authentication. It seems that if you have Chrome Services on your phone in which you are logged in, than your account's session is shared with the Flutter Web App and you don't need to log in every time